# Aggregate takes a long time

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am using aggregate function to do the aggregation by

```
aggregate(x=df$time,by=list(df$id),FUN=sum)
```

My table is having 100 million records and it takes hours to take the results.How can I reduce the time of this process.Any help is appreciated?

Comment: So did you go thru the options here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group ?

Comment: ahh...that is better

Comment: Yeah I went through this but not much difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you loading your initial table with the `data.table` library? This will save a significant amount of time just loading 100m rows.

```
DT <- fread("path/to/file.csv")
```

Then you can aggregate fairly quickly with:

```
DT[ , AggColumn := sum(time), by = id]
```

Comment: Or you can just do `dt <- as.data.table(df)`.  `fread` is great but its automatic classification for columns isn't always pretty. I routinely work with data.tables of 60M+ rows; aggregations usually take _seconds_. Sometimes, worst case, minutes, if the aggregation logic is complex.